# Aspose Cells ExportDataTable CellsException

Tags: c#, aspose, aspose-cells

I am trying to read an excel file of size 263 KB, it includes 3 columns and  6998 rows of data, the first column is alphanumeric id `Site ID` ex: 'D7302', and the other 2 columns are `latitude` and `longitude` of type decimal,

```
            try
        {
            dataTable = worksheet.Cells.ExportDataTable(HeaderLineStartingRowNumber, 0, worksheet.Cells.MaxRow - HeaderLineStartingRowNumber + 1, worksheet.Cells.MaxColumn + 1, true);
        }
        catch (CellsException)
        {
            dataTable = worksheet.Cells.ExportDataTableAsString(HeaderLineStartingRowNumber, 0, worksheet.Cells.MaxRow - HeaderLineStartingRowNumber + 1, worksheet.Cells.MaxColumn + 1, true);
        }
```

this code always throws `CellsException` and exports data as string which truncates decimals and returns a string so instead of `28.125027778` it returns `28`, when i reduced the file size to 100 rows it was exported successfully as expected so it must be a size issue, so are there size limitations for `ExportDataTable` , Thank you

Comment: Is this an excel issue?

Comment: i don't think so because when i reduced the excel file size the `ExportDataTable` worked as expected

Comment: But you tagged it excel...

Comment: Probably, this issue is occurring because D7302 is a cell name and it is also your column name. We will look into it and update you on Monday or Tuesday hopefully. Regards. -- Note: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose

Comment: no no the column name is `Site ID`, D7302 is an example in this column, I updated the question

Comment: As far as I know, Aspose has good support line so you can discuss your issue there and even get a prompt patch in case of their bug confirmed.

Comment: Please check the reply I posted in this question.Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have tested your issue with the following sample code and it worked fine. We tested this issue with the [most recent version i.e. 18.4 uploaded on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Aspose.Cells/18.4.0). Please download the [sample Excel file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/thosm201f5n5sv1/Excel%20File%20-%20sampleExportDataTable.zip?dl=0) used inside the code and also see the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWKYQ.png) that shows, data from worksheet has been exported to data table successfully.

The code is exactly similar to yours with few changes so we do not find any error in your code. Therefore, if you are using the older version, you must use the most recent version.

> If your issue still occurs with the most recent version, then provide us your runnable sample code (preferably sample console application project) along with all the files used inside your code. We will execute your code at our end and try to replicate the issue and log it in our database for a fix in future releases. Thanks for your cooperation in this regard and have a good day.

**Sample Excel File used inside the Code - Download Link:**

- [sampleExportDataTable.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/thosm201f5n5sv1/Excel%20File%20-%20sampleExportDataTable.zip?dl=0)

**Sample Code**

```
Workbook wb = new Workbook("sampleExportDataTable.xlsx");

Worksheet worksheet = wb.Worksheets["Data"];

int HeaderLineStartingRowNumber = 25;

var dataTable = worksheet.Cells.ExportDataTable(HeaderLineStartingRowNumber, 0, worksheet.Cells.MaxDataRow - HeaderLineStartingRowNumber + 1, worksheet.Cells.MaxDataColumn + 1, true);
```

**Screenshot:**
[image: Export Data Table using Aspose.Cells APIs]

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose

Comment: thank you @shakeel for your detailed reply, i'm using Aspose in a visual studio solution, so i'm checking the possibility of updating it to the latest version, the current version we're using is 7.7.2.0, the problem is that other parsers are using Aspose also so i'm afraid this might have an effect on other parsers

Comment: thank you @shakeel the problem was with the first column having mixed datatypes, so i explicitly defined the columns data types woth `ExportTableOptions`

Comment: @EliasGhali, it is good to know that you were able to sort out this issue. In case, you face any other issue, please feel free to let us know. We will be glad to help you further. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error by this line code:

```
var dataTable = worksheet.Cells.ExportDataTable(0, 0, worksheet.Cells.Rows.Count
, worksheet.Cells.Columns.Count, true);
```

Then change it to these codes and the error resolved:

(**ExportTableOptions** and **ExportAsString**)

```
ExportTableOptions options = new ExportTableOptions();
options.ExportAsString = true;
options.ExportColumnName = true;
var dataTable = worksheet.Cells.ExportDataTable(0, 0,worksheet.Cells.Rows.Count, worksheet.Cells.Columns.Count, options);
```